# How can I create a new website in IIS in stopped state using Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

Using the following command, I can create a website:

```
PS IIS:\Sites> New-Item iis:\Sites\TestSite -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:TestSite"} -physicalPath c:\test
```

But, the newly created website is in Started state.

How can I create it in stopped state?

Comment: Is it problematic to stop it immediately?

Comment: `new-website -Name "Test" -PhysicalPath D:\Bla -Port 80 -HostHeader "Test" | stop-website` would stop it immediately

Comment: but it will be started for even a millisecond. There is an option in GUI to no to start it after creation (https://www.serverintellect.com/support/windowsserver/iis7-create-site/). I am wondering if it's possible in PS as well.

Answer (score 1):

When I tested it, The Site got automatically started as soon as I specified BindingInformation. So either you set the BindingInformation later, or stop the website immediately after creation

btw. I would use `New-Website` instead of `New-item`

This will create the website and immediately stop it (it will run for some milliseconds though):

```
new-website -Name "Test" -PhysicalPath D:\Bla -Port 80 -HostHeader "Test" | stop-website
```

This will create the Website without binding information and then set the binding information.

```
New-Website -Name "Test" -PhysicalPath D:\Bla -Force | % { Set-Webbinding $_.Name -PropertyName "HostHeader" -Value xy }
```

It's a workaround since I don't see any way to specify that you don't want to start the website when using `New-Website`

Comment: I am looking for something without "it will run for some milliseconds though"

Comment: @HosseinMargani the second command is without "it will run for some milliseconds though"